# 6502 Assembly: confused about arithmetics

Tags: assembly, hex, 6502

I'm new to 6502 Assembly and hexadecimal in general, so I'm really confused about how arithmetics work.

For example:

```
LDA #$c0
TAX
INX
ADC #$c4
BRK
```

`c0 + c4` is too big for a byte, implying that it's `192 + 196`. Thus setting the carry flag and resulting in the hex value `84`.

But on the other hand, doing only `LDA #$c0` sets the negative flag, implying that `c0` isn't actually `92` but `-64`. So the operation becomes `-64 + -60`. That result is `-124`. That would "fit" as it's still the hex value `84`.

I just can't wrap my head around it. Does 6502 Assembly use `0` to `255` for hex values or `-127` to `127`? Why does the code above set the carry flag?

Comment: The CPU doesn't care what it is, it just does binary operations that produce both sets of flags.  It's up to you to write code that looks at the relevant flags for signed vs. unsigned numbers.  And BTW, the 2's complement 8-bit range is from -12**8** to +127.

Comment: "Compared to other systems for representing **signed** numbers (e.g., ones' complement), two's complement has the advantage that the fundamental arithmetic operations of addition, subtraction, and multiplication are **identical** to those for **unsigned** binary numbers ... This property makes the system simpler to implement, especially for higher-precision arithmetic." (In this case, higher precision means for > 1 byte.) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Aside: `ADC` adds in the present `C`arry flag, as well as setting it as part of the result. So you need `SEC` or `CLC` first, unless you want to add in its previous value. Other instructions affect `C` too. The 6502 does not have an `ADD` instruction.